# Coloring an SVG by using CSS only?

Tags: html, css, svg

I've been through hell and back trying to get an SVG colored directly through CSS without changing the properties in the actual file.
I am trying to fill an `SVG` in `CSS` with a new color but I don't get it to work.

Targeting the SVG element inside the object element seems to work with the CSS `fill: red` property in the Inspector of Google Chrome, but doing the same in code doesn't do anything.

The original SVG file doesn't have any fill properties.

If someone could tell me what I can do about this, it'd be awesome

Comment: You can not use the page’s CSS to format elements in SVG images that are embedded into the document via `object` or `img` - the SVG element needs to be part of the document directly. https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-6

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you are using the contents of the SVG and not just as an image/object**:

I've been through the same process you have, wasting many days trying to figure this out. Months later, I found out there's a simple attribute you can place on the file to achieve this. I know you said you didn't want to change the file, so if you don't - you can use the dirty trick I did which is using javascript to take out the contents of the SVG, create a new `div` and place the contents inside of it.

If you *can* modify the file slightly, though, you can add:

```
fill="currentColor"
```

And then it will take the color of its ancestor.

```
<svg ...>
    <path fill="currentColor" ... />
</svg>
```